# Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand

Tags: python, flask

```py
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    if current_user.is_authenticated:
        return render_template('index.html', user=current_user)
    if request.method=="POST":`
        user = User.query.filter((User.username==request.form['credential']) | (User.email==request.form['credential'])).first()`
        if user is None or not user.check_password(request.form['password']):
            flash('Invalid username or password')
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
        login_user(user, remember=request.form['remember_me'])
        next_page = request.args.get('next')
        if not next_page or url_parse(next_page).nextloc!='':
            next_page = url_for('user', username=current_user.username)
        return redirect(next_page)
    return render_template('login.html', title='Sign In')

@app.route('/user/<username>')
@login_required
def user(username):
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=username).first_or_404()
    return render_template('user.html', user=user)
```

I don't know what's the problem here.

I am trying to log in, but I am getting a Bad Request 400 error.
If I put the wrong login credentials, the code works as expected.
Can anyone solve this issue?